# How to convert an apache poi workbook to a spark dataframe?

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-poi

I am reading a blob of an excel file from the database. Each file contains only one sheet in it. Using Apache poi I am converting it into a workbook like below.

```scala
val wb = w.getWorkbook(blob)
```

Now I want to convert it to a spark dataframe to process it. What is the best way to do it directly without saving it to disk?

I want to convert it in scala like,

```scala
val df: DataFrame = workbookToDf(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create iterator,

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = w.getWorkbook(blob).getSheetAt(1).iterator;
```

iterate over sheet and put cells values into 2d array,

```
Object[][] tab = new Object[rows][cols];
```

.iterator() iterates over row, inside this loop you have to create cell iterator to iterate over "columns" too.

```
Object[][] tab = new Object[rows][cols];

Iterator<Row> rowIterator = w.getWorkbook(blob).getSheetAt(1).iterator;

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    // For each row, iterate through all the columns
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        // Check the cell type and format accordingly
        cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
        tab[cell.getRowIndex()][cell.getColumnIndex()] = cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
}
```

then convert your 2d array to Seq/List/Array of Strings, where String will be concatenated elements of rows. In next step create RDD using sc.parallelize, in map step split your string and create `RDD[Row]`. I will look like this:

```
val yourRDD = rdd.map(RowFactory.create(_.split(yourDelimiter)))
```

and then use `spark.createDataFrame(yourRDD,schema)`